# ShareActionProvider from support.v7 not clicking

Tags: android

I am trying to get a working "share" button on the title bar. Initially, I followed the advice on developers.android.com for this, but got an exception saying that I needed to use MenuItemCompat. I am doing so, but now my share button won't even "click". 
My relevant code is:

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d("CYCLE:","onCreateOptionsMenu()");
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_to_do_list, menu);
        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        setShareIntent();
        mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName("my_share_history.xml");
        return true;
    }

public void setShareIntent(){
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text to share");
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
}
```

and my menu item in XML is:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="Share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

am I missing something to make this button be clickable? (I am not even talking about functionality yet. Simply the ability to be clicked (you know, like with the clicking/tapping animation).
thanks.

Comment: call setShareIntent() at end of the updateShareInfo().

Comment: My bad, I pasted it and removed comments and, among them, I removed the call. Anyways, I changed the code a bit, but the button is still not clickable....

Answer (score 0):

Have you set [share Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)? Without the share Intent, Android would not know what exactly need to be shared by the provider.

Comment: I added the full code I am testing. I update / create the intent in the onCreateOptionsMenu method.